# Virtual Microphone and skype

Tags: windows, drivers, audio, skype, windows-server-2003

I need to have at least one microphone on Windows to make Skype calls, but i have a VPS with Windows 2003 server with no audio device.

I googled a lot and finally i found something called "Virtual Audio Cable", a tool to install virtual audio drivers ( http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.html ).

I tried many times but i couldn't get this driver work, so i'm asking if someone know a similar solution, i mean a virtual microphone or a way to make skype working without any microphone.

Thanks all!

Comment: When you say "no audio device", you mean there is no physical audio device, or that it's not activated?

Comment: the first one, there is no physical audio device.

Comment: And what exactly do you need to achieve? Because from the description, it looks like you want to make phone calls on Skype, from a machine without audio (no microphone is the center of this question, but without audio output as well, if no device). So I'm not sure I understand what you want to do with Skype, if you can't hear nor talk.

Comment: (Asking for more details not only for curiosity, but also to see if there could be other solutions for your actual need, not specific to Skype, for example)

Comment: i'll explain: i need to make non-answered calls using skype api from skype to cellphones. To do so, i need a microphone in order to get skype working, because without a mic. Skype doesn't allow user to make any call. I mean, i don't need audio for this kind of call, because they don't need to be answered.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the details. Indeed, no workaround possible, you actually need Skype to work without audio.

Comment: Any suggestion ?  some kind of virtual audio device?

Comment: The only one I can find is the one you referred to, "Virtual Audio Cable" (http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.html). Maybe someone else will have a better solution.

Comment: You should elaborate on the problems you're experiencing with VAC. I've used VAC for years on several Windows versions without any issues.

Comment: you should try the free alternative called VB-CABLE (www.vb-cable.com) and for more routing/mixing services : Voicemeeter, the Virtual Audio Device Mixer.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues with virtual audio cable. If you really want to make Skype work, try using your Stereo mix. Generally, most computers have it installed already and it counts as a microphone. Basically, it's like setting your sound card as a microphone.

If you need to find it: go to your recording devices, right click, show disabled devices. From there you just right click and enable.

When making calls or listening to calls make sure that you mute the microphone. If the user on the other side talks too loud, your mic can play his/her voice back and if their mic picks it back up, you create a loop of building sound. It'll get louder and louder until it's just a screech. Seriously, mute it or change the audio setting so that it's impossible to key up.

Answer (score 0):

"Virtual Audio Cable" is not supported on VPS server. The VPS user doesn't have the right to install the kernel lever software. You need dedicated server to run the "Virtual Audio Cable".

Answer (score 0):

Dario,

Techice is right.  Access to audio devices requires full access to a machine.  The definition of VPS is Virtual Private Server.  VPS instances can be as open as 2 VPS's per physical server to as dense as 64 VPS's per physical server.  Because two VPS's, or more, exist on a physical box access to the audio hardware is disabled.

I believe you are accessing your Windows VPS via RDP.  The Windows RDP implementation only allows for outbound audio (headphones) and not inbound audio (microphone).

A Windows VPS used for Skype will allow you:

- Text chat interaction
- Outbound audio from a Skype contact
- Outbound video from a Skype contact

The VPS used for Skype will not:

- Allow audio to be sent to the Skype contact
- Allow video to be sent to the Skype contact

If your Skype requirements fall within the allowed items, then proceed with the VPS.  Otherwise you will need to find an alternative Skype solution.

Comment: Aren't VPSes fully virtualized hardware? If so, this means that the customer has full administrator access on the virtual machine, right? Then what's stopping him from installing a *virtual* audio driver on the machine, which doesn't actually use any piece of hardware?